# Combinations and permutations (arrangements of "Tomorrow" w/ conditions)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

How many different arrangements of the word "TOMORROW" with R's at the end and O's not together?
This was one of the questions in my exam today.
What I did was I found that when R's are at the ends, there are $6!/3!$ arrangements and when R's are the ends and O's are together, there are $4!$ arrangements. So this means $120-24=96$.
However a lot of the people were getting only $24$ arrangements as the answer. Please help and let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: So, start by putting the `R`s at the end.  We are left with arranging `TOMOOW`.  Now... the phrase "The `O`'s not together" can mean one of two things.  Either we just want to make sure that the `O`'s do not form a single contiguous block of letters like in `TMOOOW` counting as "bad" but `TOMOOW` counting as "good", or we want no `O` to be touching any other `O` so both `TMOOOW` and `TOMOOW` count as "bad" while `TOMOWO` counts as "good"

Comment: If we were to go with the first interpretation where we allow some touching `O`'s so long as they don't all form a single contiguous block, then your answer is correct.  If we don't want any `O`'s touching, arrange the `TMW` and then pick three of the four spaces between or to the sides of these to place the `O`'s to get a total of $3!\cdot \binom{4}{3}=24$.

Comment: oh I get it now thank u sm!